# mongodb - one collection per shard

Tags: mongodb, multi-tenant, database-replication, sharding, replicaset

My system is built on multi-tenancy, and I'm intending to apply database sharding and replica set on it. This is new to me, so I have some questions below:

1. Is it possible to partition collection disjoint to one shard only? That means instead of splitting some documents in 1 shard and some others in another shard, I want to put 1 collection completely in 1 shard, and another collection completely in another shard. Because my multi-tenant system is built on schema-per-tenant, so 1 collection represents 1 tenant. Putting each of them completely in 1 shard would make aggregate query more reliable with in that tenant's scope.
2. If MongoDB is unable to support the answer of question 1, how can I aggregate the queried data among shards correctly if a collection's documents are scattered?

I want to know the full extent of support provided by DBMS instead of delegating the logic into backend. Thank you very much

Comment: You can have unsharded collections. Those will remain in a single shard. However, all those collections within the same database will be on the same shard. So in your scenario, you would need to have a database per tenant. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-shards/#primary-shard

Comment: For 2: MongoDB does this automatically using the `mongos` process, which acts as a query router between your application and the shards.

Comment: If you want to stick with one huge collection shared by all tenants, you can still choose to put all data for one tenant on the same shard by using the tenantId as the sharding key. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#shard-key